# Checkout page displays blank

Tags: magento2, checkout

I have tried to order from Magento 2,

When I click on '**Go to checkout**' button, it goes to the checkout page but the Checkout page is a blank page. 
It displays the menu bar, header, footer, and everything but doesn't display the content of the checkout page.

What is the issue?
What can be the issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

To find out the issue

Put your site into developer mode

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean

And load again.